# R ggplot2 - why does geom_boxplot ignore aesthetics "ymin", "lower", "middle", "upper", "ymax"?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, outliers

For some testing purposes, I am trying to make boxplots where the upper and lower whiskers extend to the max and min data points (respectively), instead of treating them like outliers.

Not completely sure how this can be done best, but I figured I would just change my definition of upper and lower whisker to `max()` and `min()`, and pass them to `geom_boxplot` as `ymin` and `ymax` aesthetics (as indicated here: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_boxplot.html)

However, even when I get no warnings or errors, those aesthetics seem to be completely ignored.

See the MWE below with `iris` data:

```
data("iris")
iris_long <- as.data.frame(tidyr::pivot_longer(subset(iris, Species=="setosa"), -Species, names_to = "Var", values_to = "Value"))
iris_long_dt <- data.table::data.table(iris_long)
ddf <- as.data.frame(iris_long_dt[,list(y0=min(Value, na.rm=T),
                                        y100=max(Value, na.rm=T)),
                                  by=list(Var=Var)])
iris_long <- merge(iris_long, ddf, by="Var")
grDevices::png(filename="test.png", height=600, width=600)
P <- ggplot2::ggplot(iris_long, ggplot2::aes(x=Var, y=Value)) +
     ggplot2::geom_boxplot(ggplot2::aes(fill=Var, ymin=y0, ymax=y100),
                           position=ggplot2::position_dodge(.9)) +
     ggplot2::stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="point", shape=5, size=2) +
     ggplot2::theme_light()
print(P)
grDevices::dev.off()
```

This is what I get (which is identical to not passing `ymin` and `ymax`):

[image: test]

What I would expect is that the whiskers would extend to the min and max outlier data points (and hence the outliers not plotted, since they would not be outliers anymore).

Why is this happening? Am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible to provide only some of the boxplot stats. If you want to draw a boxplot manually you have to provide all stats and use `stat="identity"`.

But to extend the whiskers over the whole data range you could use `coef=Inf`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris_long, aes(x = Var, y = Value)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Var),
    position = position_dodge(.9), coef = Inf
  ) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point", shape = 5, size = 2) +
  theme_light()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! this is exactly the response I needed! However, I have a small problem... in some of my real cases the data is squashed, and boxplots have no lower whisker... in those cases, when I do `coef=Inf`, the boxplot is not drawn at all...

Comment: is there another value to `coef` that would solve this issue? or should I still have to calculate manually all the boxplot values like I was trying?

Comment: Hm. You could try with a different value. The default for coef is 1.5, i.e. the whisker extends from the "hinge" (the top/bottom of the box) to 1.5 * IQR. Hence any large enough value like 10, 100 or 1000 should do the job. Otherwise, if you need full control you have to compute the boxplot stats manually.

Comment: I get the following message with coef=Inf and with data with a lot of 0s (no NAs): `Computation failed in stat_boxplot(): missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed` and the boxplot is not drawn

Comment: Have you tried with a different value? I just checked by setting all values to zero. Doing so I got the same warning you mentioned. But using a finite value e.g. 1e6  worked fine.

Comment: thanks! it does work... but in the end for my purposes I am opting to go the route of defining every aesthetic and use stat="identity"